# Memory leak with simple slideshow code when changing image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks

beginner to JavaScript here. I've made a simple slideshow script, which functions by changing the CSS for background-image on the imgcontainer div. Below is a simplified version of my code and HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div id="imgcontainer" style="background-image: url(img/slider/image1.jpg); width: 500px; height: 500px;">
        </div>
        <button id="previmg" onclick="changePage(1)">Prev img</button>
        <button id="nextimg" onclick="changePage(0)">Next img</button>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var element = document.getElementById("imgcontainer");

        var timer = setTimeout(autoPage, 5000);

        var images = ["img/slider/image1.jpg","img/slider/image2.jpg","img/slider/image3.jpg","img/slider/image4.jpg","img/slider/image5.jpg","img/slider/image6.jpg","img/    slider/image7.jpg","img/slider/image8.jpg"];
        var currentImage = 1;

        function autoPage() {
            if (currentImage === images.length) {
                element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[0] + ")";
                currentImage = 1;
            } else {
                element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[currentImage] + ")";
                currentImage ++;
            }

            timer = setTimeout(autoPage, 5000);
            console.log("image autopaged to page " + currentImage + ", image src now: "  + images[currentImage - 1]);
        }

        function changePage(i) {
            clearTimeout(timer);

            if (i === 0) {
                if (currentImage === images.length) {
                    element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[0] + ")";
                    currentImage = 1;
                } else {
                    element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[currentImage] + ")";
                    currentImage ++;
                }
            } else if (i === 1) {
                if (currentImage === 1) {
                    element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[images.length - 1] + ")";
                    currentImage = images.length;
                } else {
                    element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[currentImage - 2] + ")";
                    currentImage --;
                }
            }

            timer = setTimeout(autoPage, 5000);
            console.log("image paged to page " + currentImage + ", image src now: " + images[currentImage - 1]);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

The slideshow itself seems to function fine... except for a giant memory leak it has in Chrome. Each time the image changes, the tab memory usage increases by large amounts, sometimes 10mb, sometimes 50mb. This trend continues until the memory usage seems to cap out at some certain point.

Firefox doesn't seem to exhibit this behavior, instead cycling through the images with no memory issues at all.

Is this some weakness in my coding, or is it a Chrome issue? I've tried both setting the background-image CSS as above, and directly setting the source of an image tag.

Any help with this issue or comments on the code itself would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Chrome thing, it sets the background image and keeps the old image in cache for re-usability. 
BUT: when an image is loaded that was shown before, the memory should not increase.

Your code seems fine to me.

Personally I would this slighly different. If you want to use javascript for this, it can be handier to do it the following way:
for each image you want to present: create an image (like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)

```
var myImage = new Image(100, 200);
myImage.src = 'picture.jpg';
```

then in the loop, tell a different function to set the image to the currently wanted image:

```
function SetImage(wantedUrl){
 // here put the image inside the div
}
```